# Visual Studio 2015 Universal Windows Platform Red Line in c# code Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedAssemblyException

Tags: c#

My mainpage.xaml.cs code which is 
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public MainPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
    }
}

always in red line.when i toggle for quick fixes. predefined system void is not defined and type object defined in assembly that is not referenced. you must add mscorlib version 4.0.0.0.

then in my mainpage.xaml

> an unhandled exception error has occured
>
> Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedAssemblyException Type universe
>   cannot resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0,
>   Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.SimpleUniverse.Microsoft.MetadataReader.ITypeUniverse.ResolveAssembly(AssemblyName
>   name)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeNameParser.DetermineAssembly(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName, Module defaultTokenResolver, ITypeUniverse universe)
>   at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeNameParser.<>c__DisplayClass1_0.b__0(AssemblyName
>   assemblyName)    at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String
>   asmName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Boolean throwOnError,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4
>   typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String
>   typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4
>   typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.TypeNameParser.ParseTypeName(ITypeUniverse
>   universe, Module module, String input, Boolean throwOnError)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.UnresolvedTypeName.ConvertToType(ITypeUniverse
>   universe, Module moduleContext)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataExtensionsPolicy20.TryTypeForwardResolution(MetadataOnlyAssembly
>   assembly, String fullname, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.<GetType>b__30_1(Assembly
>   assembly, String simpleTypeName, Boolean ignoreCaseInCallback)    at
>   System.TypeNameParser.ResolveType(Assembly assembly, String[] names,
>   Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4
>   typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase,
>   StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String
>   typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean
>   throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)    at
>   System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4
>   typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name,
>   Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase)    at
>   Microsoft.MetadataReader.MetadataOnlyAssembly.GetType(String name)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.GetReferenceType(Type
>   runtimeType)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.TryGetReferenceType(Type
>   runtimeType, Type& referenceType)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.InternalGetType(Type
>   type, ExternalType externalType, IType& returnValue)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.GetType(Type
>   type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.GetPlatformType(String
>   typeName, ITypeId typeId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.Metadata.PlatformMetadataBase.ResolveType(ITypeId
>   typeId)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.XamlDesigner.Metadata.XamlPlatformMetadata.CreateExternalType(IPlatformTypes
>   sourcePlatformTypes, IAssembly runtimeAssembly, IAssembly
>   referenceAssembly, Type keyType, Type replaceType, ITypeId baseType,
>   ITypeId neutralType, IXmlNamespace xmlNamespace, String clrNamespace,
>   AttributeCollection attributes, ProxyPropertyDescription[] properties)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.Metadata.WindowsUIXamlPlatformMetadata.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.WindowsXamlDesigner.WindowsStoreXamlPlatform.Initialize()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Platform.PlatformCreatorBase.CreatePlatform(IPlatformReferenceAssemblyResolver
>   referenceAssemblyResolver)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetProjectContext(IHostProject
>   project, IPlatform platform, Boolean create)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.Project.ProjectContextManager.GetSourceItemContext(IHostSourceItem
>   sourceItem)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.Designer.DesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass12_0.b__0(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Type universe cannot
>   resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.
>
> Server stack trace:     at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalInSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallModality callModality, String methodName, String filePath, Int32
>   lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalIn(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality, String
>   methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalIn(IRemoteObject
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, CallModality callModality,
>   ApartmentState apartmentState, String memberName, String filePath,
>   Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.MarshalInWithCancellation[TResult](IRemoteCancellationToken
>   remoteToken, Func`2 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.RemoteDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink._PrivateProcessMessage(IntPtr
>   md, Object[] args, Object server, Object[]& outArgs)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Messaging.StackBuilderSink.SyncProcessMessage(IMessage
>   msg)
>
> Exception rethrown at [0]:     at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage
>   reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)    at
>   System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData&
>   msgData, Int32 type)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.IRemoteDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IRemoteHostProject
>   remoteProject, IRemoteHostSourceItem remoteItem, IRemoteHostTextEditor
>   remoteEditor, IRemoteCancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.CreateDesignerImpl(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, IHostSourceItem item, IHostTextEditor editor,
>   RemoteCancellationToken remoteCancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass14_0.b__0(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds, RemoteCancellationToken remoteToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.<>c__DisplayClass5_0`1.<MarshalOutWithCancellation>b__0(IRemoteDesignerService
>   ds)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.<>c__DisplayClass27_0`1.b__0()
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.Call.InvokeWorker()
>
> System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException Type universe cannot
>   resolve assembly: System.Runtime, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a.    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.WaitForCompletion(NestedCallContext
>   nestedCallContext, BlockingCall call, WaitHandle timeoutSignal)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOutSynchronous(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, CancellationToken cancelToken, String methodName,
>   String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.STAMarshaler.MarshalOut(Action
>   action, Int32 targetApartmentId, WaitHandle aborted, CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, WaitHandle
>   timeoutSignal, String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)
>   at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.ThreadMarshaler.MarshalOut[TValue](RemoteHandle`1
>   targetObject, Action`1 action, CancellationToken cancelToken,
>   CallSynchronizationMode syncMode, ApartmentState apartmentState,
>   String methodName, String filePath, Int32 lineNumber)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.MarshalOutWithCancellation[TResult](CancellationToken
>   cancelToken, Func`3 func, ApartmentState apartmentState)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.Isolation.Remoting.LocalDesignerService.Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IDesignerService.CreateDesigner(IHostSourceItem
>   item, IHostTextEditor editor, CancellationToken cancelToken)    at
>   Microsoft.VisualStudio.DesignTools.DesignerContract.IsolatedDesignerService.IsolatedDesignerView.CreateDesignerViewInfo(CancellationToken
>   cancelToken)

eventhough it ask me to uncheck and check run the project code in xaml designer.. the problems still occur.